# Angular - formGroupName value change does not update the form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

As described in the title, `formGroupName` value change does not update the form. 
(after hitting the button the value displayed in the input remains the same)

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VTOMy4WCvuZMJAsYrULz?p=preview).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div [formGroupName]="fgn">
        <input [formControlName]="'name'">
    </div>
</form>

<button (click)="formChange()" >Change</button>

{{fgn}}
<br>
{{myForm.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {

    private myForm: FormGroup;
    private fgn: String;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fgn = 'zero';

        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            zero: this.formBuilder.group({
                name: 'Zero'
            }),
            one: this.formBuilder.group({
                name: 'One'
            })
        });
    }

    formChange() {
        this.fgn = 'one';
    }

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend like instead of using,

```
<input [formControl]="myForm.controls[fgn].controls['name']">
```

use,

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <div [formGroup]="myForm.controls[fgn]">
  <input [formControlName]="'name'">
 </div>
</form>
```

The reason is, if you have n number of input fields, for example, more than 25 fields in a form, it is not a good practice to apply `[formControl]="myForm.controls[fgn].controls['name']"` kind of declaration in each field as this will take more time and looks like a nightmare if you want to modify any simple changes.

Instead, if you use `[formGroup]="myForm.controls[fgn]"`, it will take care of the inner `[formControlName]` by itself. And this works well as I'm using it in my project.

Thanks to @Amit for initiating this idea in me.

Hope this helps. Happy optimized coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Venkatesh. The correct way to use dynamic form group on same element is [formGroup]="myForm.controls[fgn]".

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why it didn't work with the `formControlName` approach.

This seems to work though:

```
<input [formControl]="myForm.controls[fgn].controls['name']">
```

**UPDATE**:

You could use this workaround for AOT:

```
<input [formControl]="myForm.get(fgn + '.name')" />
```

(This is considered a workaround since this invokes the `get` method way too often)

Comment: This works but,
I have read that `.controls.foo.controls.bar` creates problems with AOT,
and an explanation of why this happens would interest me, so I will wait a bit before making your answer the approved one. Thanks a lot in any case

Comment: I think it creates issues because the first `.controls[something]` is of type `AbstractControl` and not `FormGroup` necessarily. That's why it doesn't necessarily have `.controls` for itself, hence the type error which prevents AOT I guess. I don't use AOT so I don't really know for sure.

Comment: If they made it so you can use `(something.controls[somethingElse] as FormGroup).controls[...]` that'd be perfect. Maybe they did?

Comment: Check out my updated answer, hope this actually helps.

Comment: With latest version (StrictTemplate = true), using this creates 2 problems. First of all, you now get a compilation error: `AbstractControl | null is not assignable to FormControl` (FormGroup.get() methods returns AbstractControl | null). The second is that FormControl doesn't get updated if you change the Input data as long as the [binding] is made with a function and not a value, so Angular won't be able to update the value of the Input correctly. The only way I found at the moment is to force the any type with `$any(myForm.get(fgn + '.name')")` but this doesn't solve the second problem.

Answer (score 2):

You were doing wrong. Correct code will be :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div>
        <input [formControl]="myForm.controls['zero'].controls['name']">
        {{myForm.controls['zero'].controls['name'].value}}
    </div>
</form>

<button (click)="formChange()" >Change</button>

{{fgn}}
<br>
{{myForm.value | json}}
```

**Explanation**

`formControlName` expects name of form control but you were using in a wrong way => `[formControlName]`. When you are passing a form control object rather than name of form control then you use `[formControl]`.
Hope this will help

Comment: I am aware of the difference between passing an object to `[formControl]` and a string to `[formControlName]`. My actual question is why it does not update in the string case.

Comment: Reactive forms binds with inputs. Normally angular do it for you with simple formGroup object. You just need to tell angular that i'm using a formGroup object at top of form and angular will able to extract formcontrol object by just formcontrol name. But Angular will not able to do the same with nested forms. To do this you need to bind your input with the object of formcontrol.

Comment: Spent the whole day today trying to work out this problem and finally came across this post. Works great! Shame Angular haven't fixed this yet. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I've solved it in the following way:
I removed (click)="saveItem()" from button, and instead added (submit)="saveItem()" to form. AND I had to add an ID to form, and reference it in button.

```
<form
      id="myform"
      [formGroup]="myGroup"
      (submit)="saveItem()"
    >
   ....
   </form>

   <button type="submit" form="myform">SAVE</button>
```