# Error toggling group name

Tags: angular

I have the following form:

```
currentLang: string = "en-Gb";

this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    Languages: new FormGroup({
        en-Gb: new FormGroup({
            first: new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)),
            last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
        }),
        de-De: new FormGroup({
            first: new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)),
            last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
        }),
    })
});

switchLang(newLang) {
    this.currentLang = newLang;
}
```

And the template code here:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm)" class="generalForm">

    <div formGroupName="Languages">
        <ol formGroupName="{{currentLang}}">
            <li>
                <label>Firstname:</label>
                <input id="first" type="text" formControlName="first">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Lastname:</label>
                <input id="last" type="text" formControlName="last">
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>

</form>

<button (click)="switchLang('de-De')">Switch to German</button>
```

But when I press the "switch to german button" my fields are still based on the values for "en-Gb". How can I make those fields go to the german mode? When switching the language I would have expected the fields to go blank so that I can fill the fields in for the German view.

Comment: I think this is because same `formControlName` are used. You can create all four text fields and toggle the two pairs according to the selected language.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 thanks it just seems to have to duplicate the code too much. If I had say 30 different languages this could get quite unmanageable.

Comment: Read about [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

Comment: @BlackBeard thanks I've already got a lot of examples in my app which use FormArray but this particular circumstance requires nested objects under requirements from the back end dev.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the end on this post = [Angular - formGroupName value change does not update the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151202/angular-formgroupname-value-change-does-not-update-the-form)

It seems that the moment you make the formgroupname dynamic in any way, you then have to amend the fields to be specific for that object (which wouldn't be the case if it was static). In my case I had to change the fields to this:

```
<input id="first" type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls['Languages'].controls[currentLang].controls['first']">
<input id="first" type="text" [formControl]="myForm.controls['Languages'].controls[currentLang].controls['last']">
```